# problem in making url for the site using php and ajax

Tags: php, ajax, url

I am currently working on a website www.islamicaim.com. My videos are working fine on this page http://islamicaim.com/video_play.php. I am using Ajax call for loading the videos. Videos are working fine but i have a problem search engine will not index my pages becuase these pages are being loaded through ajax. If any one can help me how i can make the url of my video something like www.islamicaim.com/category/artists/title.

Here is my flow of Data firstly i am sending request for categry selection then artist then title. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make your pages work without JS or AJAX. Make them usable the normal way. You should only be using AJAX/JS to enhance the browsing experience and not supplant it.

Modify your site so that the URL can accept a category and add this to your primary navigation

```
http://islamicaim.com/video_play.php?categiory=Naat
http://islamicaim.com/video_play.php?categiory=Qawali
```

Load the category that is passed via the querystring.

You also need to modify your site so each of your video files have their own page as well. Again, just load the correct video by reading the query string.

Once you have all of that in place, add some AJAX loading to your navigation like you have now, so that the content can be loaded via AJAX. This way, your pages won't break for users with no JS (and crawlers) because your plain navigation (with the querystrings) will kick in.